# n98-magerun - access denied

Tags: magerun

I can't use n98 magerun to create a dump of my database, I get `mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'example'@'example.de' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect` after executing `./n98-magerun.phar db:dump`

But the credentials in `app/etc/local.xml` are obviously correct, otherwise the shop wouldn't work. Is it possible that the password is too complex or the special chars like !%$§ are causing problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused because my password has special chars like `!$%` and my server does not understand UTF-8.

The solution is to execute `LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"; export LC_CTYPE`.

Solution found [here](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/issues/1011).